# Too many values error

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT t.trade_id, t.share_holder_id, t.broker_id
  FROM trades t
 INNER JOIN share_holders sh ON t.share_holder_id = sh.share_holder_id
 INNER JOIN share_holder_shares shs ON shs.share_holder_id = sh.share_holder_id
 WHERE (t.share_amount > 5000 AND shs.amount < 0 OR t.transaction_type = 2)
 GROUP BY t.trade_id, t.share_holder_id, t.broker_id
HAVING t.share_amount = (SELECT
                            SUM(DECODE(transaction_type, 1, share_amount)),
                            SUM(DECODE(transaction_type, 2, 0 - share_amount))
                           FROM trades t1
                          WHERE t.share_id = t1.share_id
                            AND t.share_holder_id = t1.share_holder_id
                            AND t.transaction_time < t1.transaction_time
                          GROUP BY t.share_amount)
ORDER BY t.trade_id, t.share_holder_id, t.broker_id;
```

I want to write a query which displays all shareholders to buy or sell more than 50,000 shares per trade or to sell shares they did not own at the time of the sale. I am getting too many values error from the sub query. How do i solve his??

Comment: Write the subquery by itself and see what it is returning.  If it's returning more than one row, decide which one you want and do something to get it.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning 2 values from the subquery. Make sure the subquery only returns 1 value. The way it is now is comparable to writing:

```
having t.share_amount = 50000 , -100
```

Which doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
t.trade_id,
t.share_holder_id,
t.broker_id
 FROM
trades t
INNER JOIN
share_holders sh
ON
t.share_holder_id = sh.share_holder_id
     INNER JOIN
    share_holder_shares shs
  ON
 shs.share_holder_id = sh.share_holder_id
WHERE
  (t.share_amount >5000 AND shs.amount <0 OR t.transaction_type = 2) 
GROUP BY
 t.trade_id,
 t.share_holder_id,
  t.broker_id
  having
  t.share_amount = 
 (
  SELECT
    SUM(DECODE(transaction_type,1,share_amount))
     FROM
      trades t1
       WHERE
     t.share_id = t1.share_id AND
      t.share_holder_id = t1.share_holder_id AND
        t.transaction_time < t1.transaction_time
     GROUP BY
     t.share_amount)
or t.share_amount =
(
  SELECT
    SUM(DECODE(transaction_type,2,0-share_amount))
     FROM
      trades t1
       WHERE
     t.share_id = t1.share_id AND
      t.share_holder_id = t1.share_holder_id AND
        t.transaction_time < t1.transaction_time
     GROUP BY
     t.share_amount)
 ORDER BY
 t.trade_id,
 t.share_holder_id,
 t.broker_id
  ;
```

Comment: In this case am getting an error 'not a group by expression' from sub query

Comment: I dont understand it because am getting not group by error inside the second sub query